Create channel in Discord interaction
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) return;

    // Check if the interaction is from the correct select menu
    if (interaction.customId === 'select') {
        // Check which option was selected
        const selectedOption = interaction.values[0];

        // Check which option was selected and respond accordingly
        if (selectedOption === 'option1') {
            // If option1 was selected, send a message
            await interaction.reply('You selected option 1 (Sell).');
        } else if (selectedOption === 'option2') {
            // If option2 was selected, send a different message
            await interaction.reply('You selected option 2 (Buy).');
        }

        // Reset the select menu to its default state after selection
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Sell',
                            description: 'This is a description',
                            value: 'option1',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Buy',
                            description: 'This is also a description',
                            value: 'option2',
                        },
                    ),
            );

        // Update the message with the new select menu
        await interaction.message.edit({ components: [row] });
    }
});

can any one help me about intercation
i want when user select option 1 have created channel in custom category
actually i tried to much but nothing was effective
..
..>
\>>
PS C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket> node .
node:events:497
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
at handleErrors (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:722:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1120:23)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:953:14)
at async _REST.request (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1266:22)
at async GuildChannelManager.create (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:171:18)
at async Client. (C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket\index.js:57:35)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:402:10)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
requestBody: {
files: undefined,
json: {
name: undefined,
topic: undefined,
type: undefined,
nsfw: undefined,
bitrate: undefined,
user_limit: undefined,
parent_id: undefined,
position: undefined,
permission_overwrites: undefined,
rate_limit_per_user: undefined,
rtc_region: undefined,
video_quality_mode: undefined,
default_thread_rate_limit_per_user: undefined,
available_tags: undefined,
default_reaction_emoji: undefined,
default_auto_archive_duration: undefined,
default_sort_order: undefined,
default_forum_layout: undefined
}
},
rawError: {
message: 'Invalid Form Body',
code: 50035,
errors: {
name: {
_errors: [
{
code: 'BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED',
message: 'This field is required'
}
]
}
}
},
code: 50035,
status: 400,
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/1224628657394421780/channels'
}
Node.js v21.7.1
PS C:\Users\vcrle\Desktop\Ticket>
error
